# PHP Includes, including Social buttons

Tags: php, javascript, html, server-side-includes

I have using this on every page of my site like below to avoid having social buttons from being displayed if site is viewed in Firefox:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
{
$isFirefox = (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Firefox") !== false);
} else {
$isFirefox = false;
}
if ($isFirefox) { echo ' '; }
else
include("/includes/social_buttons.php");?>
```

my

> social_buttons.php

contains the following code:

```
<!--=================== social buttons ==================-->
<div id="social">
<!-- Google +1 button -->
<div style="float:right;padding-top:1px;">
<script type="text/javascript">document.write('<div class="g-plusone" data-size="tall"><\/div>');</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
var z = document.createElement('script'), s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
z.type = 'text/javascript';
z.async = true;
z.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
s.parentNode.insertBefore(z, s);
})();
</script>
</div>
<!-- End Google +1 button -->

<!-- Facebook button -->
<div style="float:right;padding-right:2px;">
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
document.write('<div id="fb-root"><\/div><fb:like href="<?php echo $url;?>" send="false" layout="box_count" width="35" show_faces="false" font="arial"><\/fb:like>');
(function() {
var s = document.createElement('SCRIPT'), s1 = document.getElementsByTagName('SCRIPT')[0];
s.type = 'text/javascript';
s.async = true;
s.src = 'http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1';
s1.parentNode.insertBefore(s, s1);
})();
//]]>
</script>
</div>
<!-- End Facebook button -->

<!-- Tweet Button -->
<div style="float:right; margin-right:11px;">
<a href="http://twitter.com/share?via=youraccount&amp;count=vertical" class="twitter-share-button">Tweet</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
var a = document.createElement('script'), b = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
a.type = 'text/javascript';
a.async = true;
a.src = 'http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
b.parentNode.insertBefore(a,b);
</script>
</div>
<!-- End Tweet Button -->
<!-- end #social --></div>
<!--=================== end.social buttons ==================-->
```

Now the question, I would like to add some additional content to my social_buttons.php, which will be displayed in every browser including firefox.

So my attempt (Which did not work!) to do this was to place it all within my social_buttons.php and then call it with much simpler include call

```
<?php include("/includes/social_buttons.php");?>
```

so the content of social_buttons.php would look something like this:

```
<?php if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
    {
    $isFirefox = (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Firefox") !== false);
    } else {
    $isFirefox = false;
    }
    if ($isFirefox) { echo ' '; }
    else
    echo ("
    <!--=================== social buttons ==================-->
    <div id="social">
    <!-- Google +1 button -->
    <div style="float:right;padding-top:1px;">
    <script type="text/javascript">document.write('<div class="g-plusone" data-size="tall"><\/div>');</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
    var z = document.createElement('script'), s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    z.type = 'text/javascript';
    z.async = true;
    z.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(z, s);
    })();
    </script>
    </div>
    <!-- End Google +1 button -->

    <!-- Facebook button -->
    <div style="float:right;padding-right:2px;">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    document.write('<div id="fb-root"><\/div><fb:like href="<?php echo $url;?>" send="false" layout="box_count" width="35" show_faces="false" font="arial"><\/fb:like>');
    (function() {
    var s = document.createElement('SCRIPT'), s1 = document.getElementsByTagName('SCRIPT')[0];
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.async = true;
    s.src = 'http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1';
    s1.parentNode.insertBefore(s, s1);
    })();
    //]]>
    </script>
    </div>
    <!-- End Facebook button -->

    <!-- Tweet Button -->
    <div style="float:right; margin-right:11px;">
    <a href="http://twitter.com/share?via=youraccount&amp;count=vertical" class="twitter-share-button">Tweet</a>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var a = document.createElement('script'), b = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    a.type = 'text/javascript';
    a.async = true;
    a.src = 'http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
    b.parentNode.insertBefore(a,b);
    </script>
    </div>
    <!-- End Tweet Button -->
    <!-- end #social --></div>
    <!--=================== end.social buttons ==================-->
    ");?>

    SOME OTHER CODE I WANT TO INCLUDE
```

Is there any way of doing it?

Comment: what exactly didnt work? is the problem : they are not displaying or not working?

Comment: Just do your `is_firefox` test on social_buttons.php and use it to determine what gets displayed. What's the issue here?

Comment: You should also probably make sure your nested quotes are escaped.

Comment: You severely messed up your code. There are many syntax errors. You are mixing up `'` and `"`, you have `<?php echo $url;?>` inside your `echo`. You need to clean-up your code first. You cannot just wrap everything in a `echo` statement.

Answer (score 0):

What about [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php)?

```
if ($isFirefox)
{ 
  echo ' ';
}
else
{
  $url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

  echo <<<BLAH
  Hello World! I'm $name. <a href="$url">This is a link to this site</a>
BLAH; // important: this keyword has to be at the beginning of a line (do not add any char before this keyword)

}
```

Or escape your javascript (double quoutes)

Comment: Thanks for you answers, but I have no idea about php whatsoever, so if it is not too much to ask, if you could kindly provide me with complete code that can be placed into my include file, I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: I have cleaned-up up the code as you have suggested, everything works just fine except for the part where I have <?php echo $url;?>. Here is what I use on every page of the site `code`<link rel="canonical" href="http://<?php $url=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];echo $url;?>">`code` to get url of the page in the canonical tag and also copy very same url into facebook button. is there any way of making it work?

Comment: @Bensnik I have tried to use the suggestion you have made but it still does not work. It prints out href="$url"

Comment: I think I have done it, what I did is href="'.$url.'", Now I do not know if this was the right way of doing it, but at least it worked and works exactly as I expected it to work. Thanks to @Mathieu Imbert for sending me to the right direction and to Besnik, who had tried to help.